# Snowflake Recreate table in lab doesn't work

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working through Snowflake workshop lab tutorial.  I am up to 7.2.4/7.2.5.

The query in 7.2.4 executes fine:

```sql
set query_id = (
   select query_id 
   from table(information_schema.query_history_by_session (result_limit=>5)) 
   where query_text like 'update%' order by start_time limit 1
);
```

However the query in 7.2.5 gives an error:

```sql
create or replace table trips as (
   select * from trips before (statement => $query_id)
);
```

The error given is:

```
SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300002:1177671206; incident 8702198.
```

Any thoughts on what is going wrong here?

Comment: The error "300002" is an internal error and without going to Snowflake support there isn't much you can do but try to retry the statement.

Comment: Is the value in $query_id null? That's the exact error you'd get if it is.